# "Questions with new activity" banner broken on meta

Tags: bug

The "questions with new activity" banner is a bit broken on meta:

[image: Grey text on a grey background]

That grey rectangle just below "Top Questions" is meant to say something like "1 question with new activity", but grey on grey is a little unreadable. Not exactly critical as our meta site isn't the fastest moving site in the network :-)